# How to allow hacktivated iOS devices to receive Push Notifications?

Tags: ios, push-notification, jailbreak

I'm developing a game that runs on iOS using Unity3D, my problem is that I can't find a solution to let push notification work on jail broken and hacktivated devices. How can I do that?

Thanks

PS: I use App42 to send the push notification.

Comment: Some [related reading](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/57225/30844)